# Try-catch-rethrow - proper pattern

Tags: javascript, try-catch

If I have such code:

```
let result;
try {
    result = doSomethingThatCanThrow();
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Thrown error because <some info> ${e}`)
}

// do something with result if didn't throw
```

Is this valid pattern in JS? I don't like using `let`. I prefer `const` but I can't use it in this case because it won't be available outside `try-catch` block.

I could put whole code in `try` block and get rid of `let` but then it would be harder to read in my opinion:

```
try {
    const result = doSomethingThatCanThrow();
    // do something with result if didn't throw
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Thrown error because <some info> ${e}`)
}
```

Keep it mind that it can always grow.

Also I could always skip rethrowing but I want to add some more information to error.

Which option is better and why? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: is there any reason you wouldn't want to use a var instead of let or const?
 Both are block-scoped where var is global.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: Using `var` can lead to more bugs. It's also harder to debug code with `var`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `finally`

```js
(async(doSomethingThatCanThrow) => {

  let result;
  try {
    result = await doSomethingThatCanThrow();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Thrown error because <some info> ${e}`)
  } finally {
    if (result !== undefined) {
      // do something with result if didn't throw
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
  // do stuff 
})(() => Promise.reject(123))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: You still use `let`.

Comment: Is the specific requirement to not use `let`?

Comment: @Daniel What is the use case for using `const` instead of `let`? Note, the original Question specifically asks _"Are there any other possibilities?"_

Answer (score 0):

*Try* a test condition to see if the variable **result** is empty, or not!

```js
var result
try {
    result = "This time it worked!";
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Thrown error because <some info> ${e}`)
}

if (result) {
    console.log(result)
}
```

```js
var result
try {

} catch (e) {
  }

// do something with result if didn't throw

if (!result) {
    // var result undefined
    // Result not thrown!
    console.log("Failed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the only real way to avoid let (other than using `var` as another response suggested - don't do that), is to extract this try-catch into a function and return the result directly with the try block, i.e.

```
const doSomethingThatCanThrowAndRethrowWithUpdatedMessageIfFails = () => {
  try {
    return doSomethingThatCanThrow();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Thrown error because <some info> ${e}`);
  }
}

const result = doSomethingThatCanThrowAndRethrowWithUpdatedMessageIfFails();
```